# Make Node.js exit regardless of a native module async call pending

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

I'm writing a [Napi](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html)-based module for Node.js.

The module uses WINAPI `WaitForSingleObject(pid)`. The blocking WINAPI call is wrapped in `Napi::AsyncWorker`.

#### The issue

The async call prevents Node.js from exiting. I want Node.js to exit when it has nothing else to do, like it does with `child_process.unref()`. So I want to unref the async call from the Node.js event loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time to make a NPM package of it, but here is my solution. The solution is valid for all blocking system calls (that put the calling thread to the waiting state, like `Sleep()` does).

The idea is to:

1. Use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) for the blocking WINAPI call.
2. Use [`napi_threadsafe_function`](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_napi_threadsafe_function) to call back from the new thread to Javascript safely.
3. Use [`napi_unref_threadsafe_function`](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_napi_unref_threadsafe_function) to unref the async operation from Node.js event loop.

More details:

4. For safe simultaneous calls, create a new `void* context` with thread-specific data and pass it around (supported by N-API).
5. For the unreffed `napi_threadsafe_function`, finalizer is supported. Stop the waiting thread here to prevent crash messages upon Node.js exit.
6. I use the C [N-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html) and C++ [node-addon-api](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api) interchangeably. Unfortunately a pure C++ solution is impossible at the time of writing because `napi_unref_threadsafe_function` is only available from the C API.

**addon.cc:**

```cpp
    #include <napi.h>
    #include <node_api.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <tlhelp32.h>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace Napi;

    struct my_context {
      std::thread nativeThread;
      HANDLE hStopEvent;
      napi_threadsafe_function tsfn;
    };

    std::string WaitForPid(int pid, my_context* context, bool* stopped) {
      HANDLE process = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, pid);
      if (process == NULL)
      {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "OpenProcess failed: " << (int)GetLastError();
        return stream.str();
      }
      context->hStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
      if (process == NULL)
      {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "CreateEvent failed: " << (int)GetLastError();
        return stream.str();
      }
      HANDLE hEvents[2] = {process, context->hStopEvent};
      DWORD waitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE);
      if (waitResult == WAIT_FAILED)
      {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "WaitForSingleObject failed: " << (int)GetLastError();
        return stream.str();
      } else if (waitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1) {
        *stopped = true;
      }
      return std::string();
    }

    Value WaitForProcessToExit(CallbackInfo &info)
    {
      Env env = info.Env();

      if (info.Length() < 3) {
        TypeError::New(env, "Wrong number of arguments").ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
        return env.Null();
      }

      if (!info[0].IsNumber() || !info[1].IsBoolean() || !info[2].IsFunction()) {
        TypeError::New(env, "Wrong arguments").ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
        return env.Null();
      }

      int pid = info[0].As<Number>().Int32Value();
      bool unref = info[1].As<Boolean>();
      Function func = info[2].As<Function>();

      // Do async stuff

      my_context* context = new my_context();

      NAPI_THROW_IF_FAILED(env, napi_create_threadsafe_function(
      (napi_env) env,
      (napi_value) func,
      NULL,
      (napi_value) String::New(env, "WaitForProcessToExit"),
      0,
      1,
      NULL,
      [](napi_env env, void* finalize_data, void* finalize_hint /* Context attached to the TSFN */) {
        SetEvent(((my_context*)finalize_hint)->hStopEvent);
        ((my_context*)finalize_hint)->nativeThread.join();
        delete finalize_hint;
      }, 
      context, // Context attached to the TSFN
      [](napi_env env, napi_value js_callback, void* context, void* data) {
          std::string* error = (std::string*)data;
          // Transform native data into JS data, passing it to the provided `js_callback` (the TSFN's JavaScript function)
          napi_status status = napi_ok;

          napi_value global;
          status = napi_get_global(env, &global);
          if (status != napi_ok)
          {
            std::cout << "napi_get_global failed" << std::endl;
          }

          napi_value result;
          if (error->empty()) {
            status = napi_call_function(env, global, js_callback, 0, NULL, &result);
          } else {
            napi_value values[] = { (napi_value)Error::New(env, *error).Value() };
            status = napi_call_function(env, global, js_callback, 1, values, &result);
          }
          delete data;
          if (status != napi_ok)
          {
            std::cout << "napi_call_function failed" << std::endl;
          }
          status = napi_release_threadsafe_function(((my_context*)context)->tsfn, napi_tsfn_release);
          if (status != napi_ok)
          {
            std::cout << "napi_release_threadsafe_function failed" << std::endl;
          }
      },
      &(context->tsfn)), env.Undefined());

      context->nativeThread = std::thread([pid, context] {
        bool stopped = false;
        std::string error = WaitForPid(pid, context, &stopped);

        if (stopped) {
          return;
        }

        napi_status status = napi_call_threadsafe_function(context->tsfn, new std::string(error), napi_tsfn_blocking);
        if (status != napi_ok)
        {
          std::cout << "napi_call_threadsafe_function failed" << std::endl;
        }
      });

      if (unref) {
        NAPI_THROW_IF_FAILED(env, napi_unref_threadsafe_function((napi_env) env, context->tsfn), env.Undefined());
      }

      return env.Undefined();
    }

    Object Init(Env env, Object exports)
    {
      exports.Set(String::New(env, "WaitForProcessToExit"), Function::New(env, Winapi::WaitForProcessToExit));
      return exports;
    }

    NODE_API_MODULE(hello, Init)
```